# How to restore a system attribute in DB

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, sql

The `special_to_date` attribute in Magento caused an error in the `catalog->products` so I decided to remove the record in `EAV_Attribute table` ?
The error disappeared but I wanna to restore the attribute since this is a system attribute.

I did this INSERT (copying the record from a backup) but I get an error:

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO  `magento_back`.`sm_eav_attribute` (
 `attribute_id` ,
 `entity_type_id` ,
 `attribute_code` ,
 `attribute_model` ,
 `backend_model` ,
 `backend_type` ,
 `backend_table` ,
 `frontend_model` ,
 `frontend_input` ,
 `frontend_label` ,
 `frontend_class` ,
 `source_model` ,
 `is_required` ,
 `is_user_defined` ,
 `default_value` ,
 `is_unique` ,
 `note`)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '4',  'special_to_date', NULL ,  'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',  'datetime', NULL , NULL ,  'date',  'Special Price To Date', NULL , NULL , '0',  '0', NULL ,  '0', NULL);
```

> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry '4-special_to_date' for key 'UNQ_SM_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_CODE'

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `sm_eav_attribute` table has an unique key for `entity_type_id` AND `attribute_code`.

You shouldn't get that error if you deleted the record. To make sure you deleted the row, you can execute the query:

```
DELETE FROM `sm_eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = '4' AND `attribute_code` = 'special_to_date' LIMIT 1
```

To make your query work even if the row is still present, you can change it to:

```
 INSERT INTO  `sm_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`)
 VALUES (NULL, 4, 'special_to_date', NULL, 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime', 'datetime', NULL, NULL, 'date', 'Special Price To Date', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `attribute_model` = '1',
    `backend_model` = 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
    `backend_type` =  'datetime', 
    `backend_table` = NULL, 
    `frontend_model` = NULL, 
    `frontend_input` = 'date', 
    `frontend_label` = 'Special Price To Date',
    `frontend_class` = NULL, 
    `source_model` = NULL, 
    `is_required` = '0', 
    `is_user_defined` = '0', 
    `default_value` = NULL, 
    `is_unique` = '0', 
    `note` = NULL;
```

You are still trying to insert, but if the row already exists, it will update the fields.